# jquery change on filename behaves differently on firefox and chrome

Tags: jquery

I am triggering on the change of filename field with this

```
$('#filename-field').change(function()
{
...
});
```

where the file dialog is invoked via a button:

```
<label class="btn" for="filename-field">SELECT FILE</label>
<input type="file"  id="filename-field">
```

It works all time in Firefox. But in Chrome if I select the same file as I did the last time, the change event does not fire.   Apparently the two browsers have different interpretations of what 'change' means.

Any thoughts on an easy way to get Chrome to recognize that choosing a file is always a change?

Comment: I'm betting their reasoning is that if the value of an input has not changed, there was no change.

Comment: Why do you need to know when the same file was selected? Doesn't seem any different than a cancel

Comment: Its something I noticed during testing.  I select a file to upload it.  Then I want to do the same thing again. It's not something an end user would do very often unless something on the server didn't work, but it's very disconcerting when you select a file to upload and nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `click` event that clears out the input before a new file is selected. This would ensure that any file selection (including re-selecting the same file again) would fire the `change` event.

```js
var $filename = $('#filename-field');
  
$filename.click(function() {
  $(this).val('');
});

$filename.change(function() {
  console.log("File was changed.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="btn" for="filename-field">SELECT FILE</label>
<input type="file" id="filename-field">
```

(You could of course chain these two events if you prefer to write it that way.)

Comment: Huh, you're right, I must be used to browser behavior of older days or something. I'll withdraw the "objection" :-)

Comment: @CBroe Not a problem :) Truth be told, I originally commented this answer as a "suggestion", and even said - "The only thing I'd be concerned about is that cancelling a selection would still clear out the input". I was equally surprised as of about 10 minutes ago when I tested that out myself haha.

Comment: In my case the click function goes on the label/button not on the field, but using that method does indeed work.  Thanks!

Comment: @FredAndrews  Clicking on the label will trigger the field's click event :)